How to protect the memory of my shared library?
I provide a C++ shared library to a client but that client has an engineer who doesn't code properly and he very often comes back to me telling he has an issue with the library when it's actually his application that does weird things (but with effect in the code of my lib).
How can I prevent the user from altering the memory of my library?
Story: One time he was doing something weird with pointer and some part of the code (sleep_for()) wasn't executed and it leads to lots of wasting time trying to debug my code. (of course he doesn't provide his code)
How do you deal with that situation? I politely says I don't have time, but at the same time I don't want to reject a true positive issue due to my lib.

If something goes wrong in your library then it is your responsibility to fix it. It does not matter what the user is doing, your code needs to be robust enough to protect itself from misuse.

You lack knowledge to understand my question,  I'll wait for someone else.

If you write-protect the memory used by your library, your library won't be able to write to it, either. It's not possible to control memory access by whether it's being used by the library or the application, unless the library runs in another process and uses message passing to communicate with the application.

If your library is not able to handle users doing "something weird" then it is your problem, not the user's. This holds true form any piece of software.

@Barmar I was afraid of that, I'm not willing to add such complexity (even tho it may be easy).

@OldBoy I told you already, you lack basic knowledge of how memory is allocated and protected. Please read some books about processes.

@OldBoy There isn't really anything a library can do to detect when some other part of the program has trampled your memory. They're causing undefined behavior and anything can happen in any part of the program. You really don't know what you're talking about.

This really is an organizational problem, not a technical one. When they tell you your library is bugged, you ask for a code sample to reproduce the issue.

@Barmar Thank you for your kind words.

I agree this is an organizational issue. There's a reason why most open source projects will only look at reported issues if there's either a) an easy way to reproduce it or b) multiple users affected. You probably need to talk to your client about improving the way they report those issues to you.

Thanks for your experience! I will do that then.

Note that even if you were able to do this, it might not solve your tech support problem. When their application tries to modify your memory, it will crash with a segmentation violation. If they're not good at debugging their code, they'll still report it to you as a crash that only happens when using your library.

It's easier to reject support for segfault (backtrace will show and all). Harder to say when the issue seems to come from my lib.

You can't do this in a shared library. The robust way to do this is to put your code in a separate process, and have a well-defined protocol between your application and their application. If the messages are correct, your process should not crash. And if they're not, you reject the incoming message.

Thanks! Do you mean IPC? I'd run my lib under a daemon app and they'd communicate with it instead of linking the lib? IPC would add latency but if that's the way, I'd do it, at least for the first integration, and I'd provide a wrapper to emulate it. Once I know it's stable, they can link my lib in their app.

@None: IPC is indeed the correct abbreviation. You'll need to decide on the business case; we're here just pointing out what you can technically do to protect your library.

If you want to give back read-only memory to your client code and don't trust it not to cast away const, then you could mmap() that memory, and use mprotect() mark it read-only once you have written it, before you return it to the caller.
But I really advise that you just use const and educate your users that const_cast() is harmful.

If it's just a matter of your library being called with arguments you don't handle, then add those cases to your unit tests and ensure that you do something sensible, such as throwing an exception.

I'm checking all the parameters given to the library. In the end the issues I have with this user isn't even related to the library, but the way they code their own app that ends up corrupting my lib's internal data.

One issue is that my code executes correctly but something broke the std::this_thread::sleep_for I use inside (validated with prints inside my lib). Hard to debug that situation... Thanks!
